# can somebody explain me what this code means please?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

this is the code :
explanation : this is interpolation in angular!

```
`{{ product.getAcceptedBid().description }}`
```

product is my property of type Product class which has a method in it named getAcceptedBid() and a propert in it named description!
at the same time getAcceptedBid() is of type Bid class which has a property in it named description!
what does this .description exactly do? and which one it's referring to? the Bid class or Product Class!?
and beside this, what does it do?
I know  product.getAcceptedBid() is calling the getAcceptedBid() method but the problem is with .descriotion part! I can not understand it!

Comment: It clearly means getAcceptedBid() methods returns list of value with one of key name 'description'. And it will return value of description.

Comment: yes!! now I got it! I was confused and did not know what was exactly happening ! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider classes `Product` and `Bid`.

```
class Product {

  public getAcceptedBid (): Bid {
    return new Bid()
  }

}

class Bid {

  public description = `foo`

}
```

As you stated, `getAcceptedBid` is a method of class `Product`, while `description` is a property of class `description`.

This means that instances of `Product`, i.e. objects created with `new Product()` will have a method `getAcceptedBid` which you can call with `product.getAcceptedBid()`. What does this method do? We look at its body.

```
  public getAcceptedBid (): Bid {
    return new Bid()
  }
```

This method creates an instance of class `Bid`, and returns it. So when you do `product.getAcceptedBid()`, you actually get an instance of `Bid`.

```
const product = new Product()
const bid = product.getAcceptedBid()
```

Now, this newly created `bid` is an instance of `Bid`, which has a property named `description`. You can, for example, `console.log` it to inspect what it's inside.

```
console.log(bid.description)
```

---

What you have is just a short version of all this, in one line (plus you already have an instance of `Product` from somewhere so no need to create it).

```
product.getAcceptedBid().description
```

You can imagine additional parenthesis, which might clear it up:

```
( product.getAcceptedBid() ).description
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\                          /
  this is instance of Bid,
  like { description: 'foo' }
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript and TypeScript (and many other object-oriented programming languages), multiple `.` accessors on the same expression are evaluated in chain *from left to right*, each on the previous result.

For your example, it means that `.description` is evaluated on the result of `product.getAcceptedBid()` expression, so that's the Bid description that is evaluated.

Note: this is really pure JS/TS, nothing special about Angular interpolation here.

> what does this .description exactly do?

It gets the value of an attribute called `description` on an object.

Answer (score 2):

In a few words: 1. Access the `product` object. 2. Then get acceptedBid value by calling a function. 3. Get `description` property of the received object in #2.

As a result, you will see just the `description` value visually on the UI in HTML.